# Co-convexity of Splines

Tags: r, splines

I wrote a Schumaker Shape-Preserving Spline in R. I am confident that I got the coding right because I get the same results as [another person in matlab](http://www.economia.puc-rio.br/lrezende/Eindex.html).

This was written based on Judd (1998, Numerical Methods in Economics, pages 231-235) who said: "The result ... is a quadratic spline that is globally monotone if the data are monotone. Similarly for convexity and concavity" Also "Preserving local curvature is also accomplished .. hence the Shumaker scheme is co-convex".

I did a spline that was globally monotone but had a nonmonotonic spline. This is detailed below. I thought that I must be misinterpretting co-convexity. **My question is how to interpret co-convexity given we can end up with this nonmonotonic result from monotonic data.**

### Example

The example I used was:

```
tt = c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6)
FF = c(2,1, 0.59, 0.27, 0.25, -0.23, -0.45)
```

Note that this is monotonic however it is not strictly convex due to the `tt = 4` data point.

The code I used to make this is available on request and not included for brevity. It is a 1:1 translation of this [matlab code](http://www.economia.puc-rio.br/lrezende/Eindex.html) however and has been checked against it.

Which gives the spline:
[image: Shumaker Spline Result]